# Appending to list using append method and + operator produces different results in Python?

Tags: python

My algorithm works perfectly when I use the `mylist + [ newmember ]` syntax.

```
class Node:
    def __init__( self, label, value, child1=None, child2=None ):
        self.label = label
        self.val = value
        self.children = []
        if child1 != None:
            self.children.append( child1 )
        if child2 != None:
            self.children.append( child2 )

b = Node( 'b', 3 )
c = Node( 'c', 12 )
a = Node( 'a', 5, b, c )

def check( path, item, slns ):
    node = path[ -1 ]
    if node.val == item:
        slns.append( path )
    if len( node.children ) > 0:
        for i in node.children:
            check( path + [ i ], item, slns )                       # <<<< This works!

def search( root, item ):
    slns = []
    check( [ root ], item, slns )
    return slns

resultpath = search( a, 12 )
for i in resultpath:
    for j in i:
        print( j.label )
```

But I changed it to this after trying it with the commented line (line 21) with the `mylist.append( newmember )` syntax (i.e. `check( path.append( i ), item, slns` ). I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tree2.py", line 28, in <module>
    resultpath = search( a, 12 )
  File "tree2.py", line 25, in search
    check( [ root ], item, slns )
  File "tree2.py", line 21, in check
    check( path.append( i ), item, slns )
        # <<<< This works!
  File "tree2.py", line 16, in check
    node = path[ -1 ]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

My reading of other answers on this site led me to believe that, when appending items and not a list, the two ways of appending to a list were equivalent apart from performance differences. Could you explain why `path.append( i )` and `path + [ i ]` produce different results in this context, and why this error is occurring?

Comment: `append` returns None. it does its operation in place.

Comment: `append` add an item to the end of the list and the plus operator results in a concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the difference is that `lst.append(item)` appends an `item` to the existing list (in-place) and returns `None` while the `+` operator (`__add__`) returns the result of the concatenation (a new list).

so when you call `check( path.append(i), item, slns )` you do modify the list `path` but you effectively call `check(None , item, slns )` instead of the new list as the first argument.

Comment: another difference is that `lst.append` is in-place whereas `l1 + l2` creates a new list.

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` is an in-place operation it does not return anything, and hence that call returns `None`.

When you do -

```
check( path.append( i ), item, slns )
```

You are actually sending the return value of `path.append()` to `check()` , the return value of `path.append()` is None , hence you send `None` as the first argument, causing your issue.

I would say if the first method works, that looks cleaner. When you use `path.append()` , it would end up append the `path` object in-place, and since you are not creating a new path `list` anywhere, it will always update the same path object, and you would end up getting wrong results.

When you do `list + list1` , creates a new list and the expression returns that.

---

Also, one suggestion is that instead of creating `slns` as a list of list, you should create a simple list , by using `slns.extend(path)` and then treat it as a simple list, Example -

```
def check( path, item, slns ):
    node = path[ -1 ]
    if node.val == item:
        slns.extend( path )
    if len( node.children ) > 0:
        for i in node.children:
            check( path + [ i ], item, slns )                       # <<<< This works!

def search( root, item ):
    slns = []
    check( [ root ], item, slns )
    return slns

resultpath = search( a, 12 )
for i in resultpath:
    print( i.label )
```

`list.extend` in python appends the elements of the iterable (not the iterable itself) that it receives as argument to the list (again this is also an in-place operation and does not return anything) .

Comment: Could you point out that in addition to the inplace/returning distinction, adding is closer to `extend` than `append`? And that `+ [ item ]` is not just a syntax as the question says but builds an actual list before adding?

Comment: I really appreciate how helpful your answer is! I marked the other one as the accepted answer because I feel it will be more instantly helpful to others reading my question.